# Given length and index - how to create an "unit" array?

Tags: haskell

How can I create an array of length `n`, all zeroes, except for some index `i` being equal to 1.0?

For example, if my magic function is `foo` it would work as follows:

```
foo:: Int -> Int -> [Double]
> foo 3 0
[1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
> foo 2 1
[0.0, 1.0]
> foo 1 1
** Exception: index greater than length!
```

Having a brain freeze...any help appreciated.

Comment: Using run-time exceptions for partial functions is generally considered un-idiomatic Haskell (`Prelude.head` notwithstanding).  You might consider changing the type to `unitList :: Int -> Int -> Maybe [Double]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
unitList :: Int -> Int -> [Double]
unitList len index
    | index < len  = replicate index 0 ++ 1 : replicate (len - 1 - index) 0
    | otherwise    = error "index out of range"
```

Note that that's a *list*, not an array. Lists have O(i) indexing, arrays O(1), so one shouldn't confuse the names of the datatypes.

Comment: Yap, I meant list. sorry. Wouldn't your code produce  Ints though? You use 0 and 1 vs 0.0 and 1.0...

Comment: The code would produce whatever `Num` type is in the type signature - if I made it polymorphic, whatever `Num` type the caller wants. Integer literals have type `1 :: Num a => a`, they stand for `fromInteger integer_with_literal_value`, so if a `Double` is required, `1` will be a `Double`, if a different type is required, it will have that.

Answer (score 1):

To create a list (as your type signature and examples suggest), you can use range syntax to create a list of indices and then call `map` to go over the indices, compare each index to the index the user supplied and map it to 1.0 or 0.0 accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
foo n k | n < 0 || n >= k = error "not in range"
        | otherwise = map (fromIntegral.fromEnum.(==k))[0..(n-1)]
```